# Is there any reason to use javac over groovyc in a mixed code project?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, gradle

In setting up a mixed java7/groovy2 project in maven or gradle, is there any reason for compiling first with javac then groovyc over just letting groovyc handle it all?

I started out compiling them separately and in their own trees (src/main/java and src/main/groovy) as best-practice suggests.  However, since java and groovy are used to solve the same problem and are so intermingled, I am now leaning towards dumping all my source into src/main/groovy and letting the groovy compiler handle both .java and .groovy files.  This seems to make the project easier to follow when looking at the source tree.  Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that `groovyc` is capable of this. I'd worry only about the bytecode that you get when doing this.

Comment: I've turned up some possible apropos docs at:  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven and http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovyc+Ant+Task
However, they seem to be implementation specific.

Comment: From experience with Groovy 1.8 under a Gradle build, compiling *.java files with the Groovy plugin produces normal Java classes without Groovy features mixed in.  (ExpandoMetaClass had no effect on pure Java classes compiled this way, for instance.)  It's possible the bytecode might be slightly different, but we didn't notice any differences when we moved from a Java build to a Groovy build and started moving things over to Groovy as necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Letting `groovyc` handle both `.java` and `.groovy` is good. This approach is also used by the `Grails` framework. Grails 2 puts all .java files under groovy source directories, like you did. What you're doing now is the best-practice.

Here's an example:
https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/tree/master/src/main/groovy/io